# How to prove the relations $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(tu)\cos(t'u)du=pp\left(\displaystyle\frac{t}{t^2-t'^2}\right)$ and

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

How to prove the relations:
$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(tu)\sin(t'u)du=\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}[\delta(t-t')-\delta(t+t')]$
and 
$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(tu)\cos(t'u)du=pp\left(\displaystyle\frac{t}{t^2-t'^2}\right)$

Comment: Showing exactly as much work as shown in the Question:  Use the [product-to-sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) identities.

Comment: Is this just half of the Fourier transform of sine? Also what is pp?

Comment: the first one is easy to prove, but the second one I do not understand. PP means principle part, it only makes sense in another integral I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the exact answer on the website called "the Fourier transform", in case anyone needs it as well I am posting the website as below:
http://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/rightSidedSinusoids.php

cheers